# Battery icon constantly empty when discharging Vaio VGN-FZ210CE

Tags: icons, battery, time

I have a Sony Vaio VGN-210CE laptop, and its battery does not report the drain rate properly. In 11.10 and earlier, the battery icon would update with the percentage, not the estimated time. In 12.04 and 12.10, it estimates by time, which is always some very low value because the estimated drain rate is 700W. I currently have 89% in my battery but the icon is red and empty. If there is an application I should install, or a setting I should change, please let me know.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

not much to do, this is a super old bug that has never been fixed apparently.
you can however keep it from suspending erroneously by typing the following in a terminal:
`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power 'use-time-for-policy' 'false'`

this will avoid your system shutting down because it thinks that it has only 1% left or so. ;)